# onclick="myform.submit()" doesn't work; says method doesn't exist

Tags: html, forms, onclick, submit

I'm trying to trigger a form submission from clicking on a link, and I'm using this as a guideline:

```
<form name="badger" action="http://www.quietdean.com">
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="badger.submit()">submit</a>
```

I have

```
<form name="epb" method="post" action="entry.php">
//I'm using CSS to make the link look like a button without being ugly like a button
<a class="edit_button" href="#" onclick="epb.submit()">Edit</a>
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $contents[0] ?> ">
<input type="hidden" name="descrip" value="<?php echo urlencode(htmlspecialchars($contents[1], ENT_QUOTES)) ?>">
</form>
```

All of the html is generated correctly by the php (I've run this in multiple browsers), including the values of the hidden inputs, but when I click on my link I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCollection> has no method 'submit'
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here?

I've tried putting the link outside the form as well but that doesn't fix it.

I've also tried taking out the class attribute of the `<a>`, but it still gives me the same error.

I've now also tried `document.forms['epb'].submit()` to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

This line needs to be closed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="descrip" value="<?php echo urlencode(htmlspecialchars($contents[1], ENT_QUOTES)) ?>">
```

It's corrected here.

Then take a look at what @m.edmonson and @Vitor42 said. It's correct.

Comment: it was closed, I just forgot to type it when i was copying the code over here, sorry :)

Comment: actually i just double checked and it is there in my post but stackoverflow doesn't display it after the ?>

Answer (score 1):

`badger` isn't an object, but just the name of the form... You should get that form as an object, and *then* invoke `submit()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding badger as an id to the form (`<form name="badger" id='badger' action="http://www.quietdean.com">`) and using `document.getElementById("badger").submit();`. I don't think badger is being found, or if it is it's not the element you are thinking it is. Also make certain there aren't any other elements on the page that have an id of 'badger'.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id="epb"` to your form, and then do this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('epb').submit()">submit</a>
```

Comment: I get:  Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'submit'

Answer (score 0):

You need your onclick attrubte to look like this:

```
onclick="document.forms['epb'].submit();"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, while the problem was the following:

I typed `<from>` tag instead of `<form>`.

`-.-"`